# Python3 using HVAC with "approle" authentication to pull secret from Hashivault

Tags: python-3.x, hashicorp-vault

Need some help please!!!

I have working code to pull a secret out of Hashi using the Management token, but...  I need to switch this around to use the "approle" type authentication and do not understand the authentication differences.

My original code used something like this:

```
def vault(KEY):
    VAULT_SERVER = "https://myserver.nowhere.com:8243"
    TOKEN = "s.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    PATH = "/secret/vault/200245/mbop200245/nonprod/testautomation/dev"
    CLIENT = hvac.Client(url=VAULT_SERVER, token=TOKEN)
    VAULT = CLIENT.read(path=PATH)
    SECRETS = VAULT['data']
    ID_PASSWORD = SECRETS[KEY]
    return ID_PASSWORD
```

Anyone have any code examples of using hvac with "approle"?  I know how to do this in API (using Insomnia) but struggling with what hvac expects... and where...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the docs? There is a whole section on Approle: https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/auth_methods/approle.html

In particular, there is this snippet for authentication:

```py
import hvac
client = hvac.Client()


client.auth.approle.login(
    role_id='<some_role_id>',
    secret_id='<some_secret_id>',
)
```

Comment: how add vault url ?

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko From [the front page of the docs](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html): `client = hvac.Client(url='https://localhost:8200')`, where you can set whatever URL you like instead of `https://localhost:8200`.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not correct here. The proper syntax seems to be:

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client()


client.auth_approle(    
    role_id='<some_role_id>',
    secret_id='<some_secret_id>',
)
```

Comment: docs are correct actually - have you tested it yourself before commenting?

Comment: Yes, I tried the documented syntax extensively before finding the alternate syntax:

for me, client.auth.approle.login() returns not implemented when using the code in the docs:

 >>> client.auth.approle.login( 
... role_id=role_id, 
... secret_id=secret_id 
... ) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hvac/api/vault_api_category.py", line 42, in getattr raise NotImplementedError('"%s" auth method class not currently implemented.') 
NotImplementedError: "%s" auth method class not currently implemented.

Comment: No.  auth_approle has been deprecated and in the most recent releases does not even exist.  While YOUR version of the library may allow it, that just means you're using something woefully out of date.  client.auth.approle is the correct syntax, currently.

Comment: Docs are correct, but you are right, I've just had the same situation with "%s" auth method in container, where on local it was fine. Taking the older auth method worked for me. And I doubt that there is something "woefully" outdated in my case. Just not the most modern docker image, can be.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is correct when combined with the comment of @nikolaybaranenko but with a correction, provide https auth information as I have. I actively manage 4 vaults and this is how my apps talk to in 1 of the environment.

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(
    url='<vault address:port>',
    verify=False
)
client.auth.approle.login(
    role_id=<role id>,
    secret_id=<secret id>,
)
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.